# Consume api in xamarin forms [POST] - serialization returns empty json object

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, httpclient

when I am converting this object to json string by using Newtonsoft.Json it returns empty objects.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
```

I keep getting this result "{}"
[image: Register Form Screenshot]

these are my codes

Registration.xaml

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
>     <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
>                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
>                  x:Class="FinalCustomerApp.Views.Registration"
>                  BackgroundImage="Background.png">
>     
>         <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
>     
>             <Label Text="Sign Up" FontAttributes="Bold" Font="50" > > >HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
>             <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
>                 <Label Text="Id" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
>                 <Entry  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="entId"/>
>             </StackLayout>
>     
>             <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
>                 <Label Text="Username" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
>                 <Entry  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="entUsername"/>
>             </StackLayout>
>     
>             <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
>                 <Label Text="Password" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
>                 <Entry  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="entPassword"/>
>             </StackLayout>
>     
>             <Button Text="Register" HorizontalOptions="Center" >x:Name="btnRegister" Clicked="btnRegister_Clicked"/>
>         </StackLayout>
>     </ContentPage>
```

Registration.xaml.cs

```
> public async void btnRegister_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         Users user = new Users()
>         {
>             mem_account_no = entId.Text,
>             mem_acc_username = entUsername.Text,
>             mem_acc_password = entPassword.Text
>         };
> 
>            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
> 
>            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, >"application/json");
> 
>            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
> 
>            var result = await client.PostAsync("http://ropenrom24-001->site1.etempurl.com/potangina/final/Restserver/index.php/users/insert",
> content);
>          
> 
>         if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
>         {
>             await DisplayAlert("Success", "Success", "OK");
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             await DisplayAlert("Failed", "My Json " + json, "OK");
>         }
> 
>         
>     } }
```

Users.cs

```
> public class Users {
>     public string mem_account_no { get; set; }
>     public string mem_acc_username { get; set; }
>     public string mem_acc_password { get; set; }
> 
>   }
```

Comment: What are those `>` doing in your files?

Comment: that's not in my files i don't know why i have those.

Comment: I guess you messed it up when clicking on the quote/code buttons in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really good with the JSON library, but I'm pretty sure you have to serialize `JObject`(s) and not directly your `Users` objects...

Each `JObject` has 1 or more `JProperty`(ies) with a name. This name will be used to generate the "serialized" Json text.

So for instance you can make something like that:

```
public class Users
{
    ... your properties ...

    public JObject ToJson()
    {
        return new JObject()
        {
            new JProperty("MemAccount", mem_account_no),
            new JProperty("MemUsername", mem_acc_username),
            new JProperty("MemPassword", mem_acc_password)
        }
    }
}
```

then to serialize your user, you seralize your JObject(s) and you can also check if there is an error during this process:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Error = delegate(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
{
    /* manage your serialization errors here.
       Usefull for debugging
    */
};

var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.ToJson(), settings);
```

Finally in your query (REST API POST request), set the content like that:

```
var requestContent = new HttpStringContent(
    jsonContent, 
    Encoding.UTF8, 
    "application/json");
```

And I Forget, If you want to deserialize back to your objects, you have to set the JsonProperty attribute on your Users's properties.

example:

```
[JsonProperty("MemAccount")]
public string mem_account_no{ get; set; }
```

It should be good... Tell me if it's clear.